# How to show that $M$ is nonsingular (iff $A-BC$ = nonsingular)$\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\C&I\\\end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

While studying matrices I came across this question:

Let M be this matrix:$\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\C&I\\\end{bmatrix}$

Where all four blocks are $n·n$ matrices, and I is an identity matrix.

Question: Show that $M$ is nonsingular iff $A-BC$ = nonsingular.

I did some crosswise multiplication and came to $A·I - B·C$ ...

Can I set the value of $I$ equal to 1? And how do I prove  $A-BC$ = nonsingular?

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\ C & I
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
I & 0 \\ -C & I
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} A - BC & B \\ 0 & I  \end{bmatrix}.
$$

(This is nothing but LU factorization in block form.) Recall that a block triangular matrix is invertible iff its diagonal elements are invertible. (See, for example [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2316555/the-inverse-of-a-block-upper-triangular-matrix).) Since $\begin{bmatrix}
I & 0 \\ -C & I
\end{bmatrix}$ has diagonal elements $I$ and $I$, it is clearly invertible with inverse

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
I & 0 \\ C & I
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Thus

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\ C & I
\end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} A - BC & B \\ 0 & I  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
I & 0 \\ C & I
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

The product of two matrices is invertible iff both are. The right matrix in the product is invertible iff $A-BC$ is invertible, as desired.

Comment: For more on Block LU and the product $A - BD^{-1}C$, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement)